# How to build a plist file to populate a Core Data relational model

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, plist

I am building a Core Data IOS application and for testing purposes, I have created a PLIST file containing demo data. My Core Data model contains multiple entities with of course multiple relationships.

Like I said, I was able to create the PLIST and have the data loaded automatically on first launch but I was able to "pre-build" the relationships.

My question is: Can this be done and if so how?

I just can't see how I can set the value of a key to another object...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In the meantime, I will thinker with attempting to re-create those relationships using "dummy indexes", if I can manage to make this work.

Comment: Do your Core Data entities have relationships? If so, what don't you understand about assigning values to those relationships?

Comment: I meant from the Property List point of view. it's not like a normal related database where you could just assign the object ID to the related field and away you go, here in Core Data the whole object is assigned to the attribute and I just don't know how to achieve that in a property list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the "Dummy Index" way worked after a fashion

Knowing what the location (index) of each object in my array of dictionaries, I was able to set the desired relationships after loading my entities with the appropriate data.

BTW, for someone attempting to accomplish the same thing, here is the procedure I took:

1. Create a new PLIST file in XCode (File -> New -> File -> IOS Resource -> Property List)
2. Populate the PLIST:

   - Under Root, added an ARRAY item for each Entity in my Data Model.
   - Within each ARRAY, added a DICTIONARY item for each Entity Object.
   - Within each DICTIONARY, added item reflecting Attributes NAMES, TYPES and VALUES.
3. Added a the following lines under the ViewDidLoad method of my first TableViewController:

   ```
   if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] < 1)
   {
       [Utilities loadDefaultDataInManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   }
   ```
4. My "loadDefaultDataInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context" method:

   ```
   + (void)loadDefaultDataInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
   {
       NSError *errorDesc = nil;
       NSPropertyListFormat format;
       NSString *plistPath;
       NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

       plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DefaultData.plist"];

       if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
       {
           plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultData" ofType:@"plist"];
       }

       NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
       NSDictionary *entities = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plistXML options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:&format error:&errorDesc];
       if (!entities)
       {
           NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %lu", errorDesc, format);
       }
       else
       {
           // ENTITY 1 data
           NSArray *entityNames = [entities valueForKey:@"EntityName"];
           for (NSDictionary *entityName in entityNames)
           {
               EntityName *newEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
               newEntity.attributeName1  = [entityName valueForKey:@"attributeName1"];
               newEntity.attributeName2  = [entityName valueForKey:@"attributeName2"];
           }

           // ENTITY 2 data
           //...

           // ENTITY 3 data
           //...

           NSError *error = nil;
           if (![context save:&error])
           {
               /*
                Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

                abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
                */

               NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
               abort();
          }
       }
       NSLog(@"Loaded Default Data");

       [Utilities setRelationshipsInManagedObjectContext:context];
   }
   ```
5. My "setRelationshipsInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context" method:

   ```
   + (void)setRelationshipsInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
   {
       NSError *error;

       // Initialize all neccessary fetch requests
       NSFetchRequest  *entityName1Request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"entityName1"];
       entityName1Request.predicate = nil;
       NSFetchRequest  *entityName2Request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"entityName2"];
       entityName2Request.predicate = nil;
       NSFetchRequest  *entityName3Request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"entityName3"];
       entityName3Request.predicate = nil;
       //...

       NSArray *entities1  = [context executeFetchRequest:entityName1Request error:&error];
       NSArray *entities2  = [context executeFetchRequest:entityName2Request error:&error];
       NSArray *entities3  = [context executeFetchRequest:entityName3Request error:&error];
       //...

       // Declaring my Objects
       Entity1 *entity1;
       Entity1 *entity2;
       Entity1 *entity2;
       // ...

       if (entities1)
       {
           for (entity1 in entities1)
           {
               // set the required relationship according to your data and schema
               if ([entity1.attributeName1 isEqualToString:@"Whatever"])
               {
                   entity2 = (Entity2 *)[entities2 objectAtIndex:0];
                   entity1.relatedAttribute = entity2;
               }
               else if ([entity1.attributeName1 isEqualToString:@"SomethingElse"])
               {
                   entity3 = (Entity3 *)[Entities3 objectAtIndex:2];
                   [entity1 addEntity3Object:entity3]; // for to many relationships
               }
               else // ... 
               {
               }
           }
       }

       // repeat the same process for your other entities that contain relationship

       if (![context save:&error])
       {
           /*
            Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

            abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
            */
           NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
           abort();
       }
       NSLog(@"Set relationships");
   }
   ```

Still would like someone to confirm or deny the possibility of doing all this from within the PLIST.

TIA,

Michel

Comment: If you're starting with a property list, something like your solution is needed. There's nothing in property lists that models relationships, because they're not designed for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you. The more I thought about this, the more I came up to the same conclusion: The object need to be instanciated before it can be put into a relionship with an other...